# Python/Regex - How to extract date from filename using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I need to use python to extract the date from filenames. The date is in the following format:

```
month-day-year.somefileextension
```

Examples:

```
10-12-2011.zip
somedatabase-10-04-2011.sql.tar.gz
```

The best way to extract this would be using regular expressions?

I have some code:

```
import re
m = re.search('(?<=-)\w+', 'derer-10-12-2001.zip')
print m.group(0)
```

The code will print '10'. Some clue on how to print the date?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming the date is always in the format: [MM]-[DD]-[YYYY].

```
re.search("([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4})", fileName)
```

Comment: note that in order to use the output of this, you will be receiving a list back:
`result = re.search("([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4})", fileName)`
`result[0]` # will give you what you want

Comment: Adding to the above [0-9]{2,4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2,4} will match '2017/02/23' and '23/02/2017' both.
Similarly, [0-9]{2,4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2,4} will match 2017-02-23 and 23-02-2017 both.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use a [capture group](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects).

```
m = re.search('\b(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\.', 'derer-10-12-2001.zip')
print m.group(1)
```

Should print `10-12-2001`.

You could get away with a more terse regex, but ensuring that it is preceded by a `-` and followed by a `.` provides some minimal protection against double-matches with funky filenames, or malformed filenames that shouldn't match at all.

**EDIT:** I replaced the initial `-` with a `\b`, which matches any border between an alphanumeric and a non-alphanumeric. That way it will match whether there is a hyphen or the beginning of the string preceding the date.

Comment: your regexp doesn't match if the filename begins with a date (as in the first example). one way to fix that would be to replace the initial hyphen in your pattern with `(?:^|-)`.

Comment: Huh, you are right. I didn't even notice that example. Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can extract the date using re.split as follows

```
$ ipython

In [1]: import re

In [2]: input_file = '10-12-2011.zip'

In [3]: file_split = re.split('(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})', input_file, 1)

In [4]: file_split
Out[4]: ['', '10-12-2011', '.zip']

In [5]: file_split[1]
Out[5]: '10-12-2011'

In [6]: input_file = 'somedatabase-10-04-2011.sql.tar.gz'

In [7]: file_split = re.split('(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})', input_file, 1)

In [8]: file_split
Out[8]: ['somedatabase-', '10-04-2011', '.sql.tar.gz']

In [9]: file_split[1]
Out[9]: '10-04-2011'
```

I ran the tests with Python 3.6.6, IPython 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

well the `\w+` you put in matches one or more word characters following a hypen, so that's the expected result.  What you want to do is use a lookaround on either side, matching numbers and hyphens that occur between the first hyphen and a period:

`re.search(r'(?<=-)[\d-]+(?=\.)', name).group(0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
**This is simple method to find date from text file in python**
import os
import re
file='rain.txt' #name of the file
if(os.path.isfile(file)): #cheak if file exists or not
    with open(file,'r') as i:
        for j in i: #we will travarse line by line in file 
            try:
                match=re.search(r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}',j) #regular expression for date
                print(match.group()) #print date if match is found
            except AttributeError: 
                pass
else:
    print("file does not exist")
```